Temperature Range for Quaker Parrots
What temperature range is adequate for Quaker Parrots (aka Monk Parakeets or Myiopsitta monachus)?
I moved recently in a colder area. The two Quaker Parrots with whom I live built their nest in a 2 cubic meters aviary, kept in a closed room. I would like to build for them a larger outside aviary like the one they had in our old place (18 square meters, 2 meters tall), but I am worried that the temperature outside might get too low for them at night.

On one hand, I know that colonies of wild Quaker Parrots  survive in British Columbia, where temperatures routinely get below zero at night in the winter.

On the other hand, there are no wild colonies of Quaker Parrots where I live, contrarily to where I used to live, so I have no empirical proof that the winter night temperature are safe for them.



Carrie Stephens from [All about Parrots] mentions Quaker Parrots in her article "How Cold Is Too Cold for Parrots? (Bird-Safe Temperature Range)", stating for them a range of safe temperatures between 20 and 22 degrees Celsius (68 to 72 Fahrenheit), with a coldest temperature of 15.6 Celsius (60 Fahrenheit), but she does not cite her sources.
